# Delete all folders in parent folder except where sub folder contains specific file

Tags: c#

I'm having problems keeping 1 folder which contains an image I want to keep.

I'm currently using the code below:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(pathToMedia);
foreach (var image in di.GetFiles())
        {
            if (!image.Name.Contains(emailImage))
               {
                 di.Delete(true);
               }
         }
```

The above does not work as I cannot seem to get the file name of the image inside the sub-folder, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you expect your file to be at the location `pathToMedia` or inside one of its subfolder?

Comment: Hi @peeyush singh inside one of the subfolders

Comment: In your description what do you think this line of code does? `if (!image.Name.Contains(emailImage))`

Comment: you are not looking in the subfolders, only the main folder. You can use `di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)` (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_DirectoryInfo_GetFiles_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_)) to find all the files in the subdirectories. Now, it's not clear, if you find the file, do you want to keep the whole parent directory and all its content, or only keep the specific sub-directory where the file resides, and delete all the subfolders and files?

Answer (score 0):

The code is not able to find the file as `GetFiles(string)` method only returns the file in the current directory and not in the sub-folders (an overload exists which allows to get all files, but that wont be useful here as we need the directory information as well). If you want to check for the files in all sub-folders then you will have to recursively do through the entire structure.

The code below shows how to do it, in your case instead of writing to console you will just check if it matches to the file you are searching.

You can see the detail about these methods in [api documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2)
As mentioned in the documentation it might be beneficial for you to use  `EnumerateFiles` in case your folders are going to have a large number of files.

```
// Process all files in the directory passed in, recurse on any directories 
    // that are found, and process the files they contain.
    public static void ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectory) 
    {
        // Process the list of files found in the directory.
        string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
        foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
            ProcessFile(fileName);

        // Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
        string [] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);
        foreach(string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
            ProcessDirectory(subdirectory);
    }

    // Insert logic for processing found files here.
    public static void ProcessFile(string path) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processed file '{0}'.", path);       
    }
```

Comment: Actually it's possible to list all the files in the subdirectories without recursion using GetFiles (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_DirectoryInfo_GetFiles_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_), but I think that wouldn't solve the problem of deleting (or not deleting) the specific subdirectory that the file came from

Comment: Thanks. It occurred to me though that it's not 100% clear from the question whether we should be keeping the whole parent folder and contents if we find this file, or only keeping the specific subdirectory, but deleting everything else. I've asked this question on the main thread.